# Time Module - strptime Django Validation Error

Tags: python, django

I've written a function to return the current fiscal year dates:

```
def get_fiscal_year(start_month=7):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.month >= start_month:
        return [time.strptime(str(now.year) + '-07-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), time.strptime(str(now.year + 1) + '-06-30', '%Y-%m-%d')]
    return [time.strptime(str(now.year - 1) + '-07-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), time.strptime(str(now.year) + '-06-30', '%Y-%m-%d')]
```

Then I'm using it in my code as follows:

```
    dates = get_fiscal_year()
    start_date = dates[0]
    end_date = dates[1]
    model = DevelopmentAssessment.objects.filter(status_id__in=[8, 7, 10], decision_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

However it's throwing the error:

```
[u"'time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=183, tm_isdst=-1)' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

As far as I could tell it's in that format, any ideas what's going on?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

From your function `get_fiscal_year` you are returning dict of `time.struct_time` objects while `__range()` needs `date` type object.

I would suggest to change your function to return `date` objects as

```
def get_fiscal_year(start_month=7):
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.month >= start_month:
    return [datetime.date(year=now.year, month=7, day=1), 
            datetime.date(year=now.year + 1, month=6, day=30)]
return [datetime.date(year=now.year-1, month=7, day=1), 
            datetime.date(year=now.year, month=6, day=30)]
```